# Счетчик просмотров постов

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте.
Хочу сделать счетчик просмотров поста, и тут возникли вопросы.

1. При просмотре поста, идет запрос на обновление поля "views". Как лучше идентифицировать пользователя который просмотрел уже этот пост.
2. Куда лучше писать ид просмотренного поста? В сессии или в куки?

Comment: Дайте точное определение просмотру. Если тот же человек посмотрел статью через неделю, это просмотр или нет?

Comment: Потом пользователю надо зайти(залогиниться), что бы видеть статьи?

Comment: Насколько критична точность?

Comment: @E_p ну вотя даже не знаю как лучше. Просто стоит задача вывести самые просматриваемые посты в категории. И если пользователь через неделю просмотрел этот же пост, то как тут лучше поступить? Просматривать посты могут хоть гости хоть пользователи. Точность особо не требуется, главное избавиться от накрутки поста. Тоесть что бы нельзя было каждый раз нажимать f5 и просмотры обновлялись.

Comment: ИМХО. Список самых читаемых статей, вещь бесполезная (просто накручивает рейтинг 10 статьям бесконечно). Гораздо полезнее читаемые за (день, неделю, месяц) или тренд. Но это реализовать архитектурно сложнее.

Comment: А можно маленький пример как сделать читаемые статьи? Тоесть как именно опредилять что они читаемые?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно оботись двумя куками (если страниц действительно много и пользователи реально много просматривают и нужен жесткий контроль)

- `user_unique_id`=`уникальное_значение (token)`
- `visited_post_id`=`id`

Первой кукой мы генерируем уникальный айди пользователя (любой супер уникальный). В `visited_post_id` записываем уникальный ID поста (или страницы). Пользователь заходит, js проверяет куки, если есть такие то куки с этими ключами то отдать их через ajax (json) на сервер и проверить в таблице mysql есть ли пользователь с идентификатором `уникальное_значение` в таблице `visited` у которого `visited_post_id` равно `id`. То есть получается если устраивать контроль, то сохранять или в браузере пользователя, или в базу.

На самом деле даже если просто хранить просмотры в кукис (в браузере), то их поместится довольно таки большое количество. Если двигатся в сторону снижения нагрузки на сервер, то есть смысл рассматривать вариант переноса "просмотренных сообщений" на сторону клиента.

Но если нужен жесткий контроль, тогда уникальный идентификатор + сессия + [куки](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-do-i-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery) + сохранять ip в mysql. Как то так. Для начала в любом случае будет неплохо генерировать уникальный id для пользователя (если такого еще нет). [Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-do-i-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery) можно посмотреть как задать куки на JQuery.

Ниже код для создания случайного токена для пользователя

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getTime();
var token=n+getRandomInt(9,99999)+getRandomInt(1,99999);
```

Comment: Так и сделую. Токен используется в приложении.

Answer (score 0):

1. Лучше всего использовать АйПи адрес.
2. Писать лучше в кукис.

Comment: А если айпи динамичный? И интересно почему лучше в куках? И как вообще это будит выглядеть? Посетитель просмотрел 100 постов иу него 100 кук будит?)

Comment: @Alex_01 Никогда не добавляте лишнее в `cookies` Браузер отправляет их с **каждым запросом**. т. е. Вы будете ганять лишние данные загружая каждую картинку, css, js ... со своего сервера!

Comment: @L.Vadim А можете рассказать на чём основаны ваши утвержения? Аргументируйте, пожалуйста. А то ответ не сильно полезен без обоснования.

Answer (score 0):

Можешь попробовать вечные куки Evercookies http://samy.pl/evercookie/ Чтоб избежать накрутки, но это конечно же не лучший вариант